# eloquent first method return collection with model variables

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Hi i've created a model which is :

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingTrait;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class leads extends Model
{
use SoftDeletes;
protected $connection = 'mysql';
protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
protected $table = 'tableName_name';
public $timestamps = false;
protected $guarded = [];
}
?>
```

and the controller look like this :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\leads;
use DB;

class billingController extends Controller
{
    public $lead;
    public function __construct(leads $lead) {
        $this->Date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $this->date = date("Y-m-d");
        $this->lead = $lead;
    }

    public function GetInfo($user) {
        $GetUserInfo = $this->lead->select('*')->where('ID', $user)->first();
        if(empty($GetUserInfo)) return false;
        else return $GetUserInfo->userInfo;
    }
}
```

supposed i want userInfo

when i echo GetInfo it return a string with curly brackets not an object as mentioned in laravel documentation first should return an object (std class) but if i print_r(GetInfo) i got something like this :

> App\Leads Object ( [connection:protected] => mysql [table:protected]
>   => tableName_name [dates:protected] => Array ( [0] => deleted_at ) [timestamps] => [guarded:protected] => Array ( )
>   [primaryKey:protected] => id [keyType:protected] => int [incrementing]
>   => 1 [with:protected] => Array ( ) [withCount:protected] => Array ( ) [perPage:protected] => 15 [exists] => 1 [wasRecentlyCreated] =>
>   [attributes:protected] => Array ( [ID] => 19 [userInfo] => 29........

is there anything i'm doing wrong ? It's supposed to return needed values as std class object what i have to change ?

Comment: When you echo GetInfo laravel converts the string into JSON.

Comment: echo doesn't convert a string into json @poldixd. echo prints exactly what it receives. if It's a string, it shows a string. if It's an object, it shows the object as a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before anything, I suggest you follow some standards when writing PHP code.

> https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Coding_conventions/PHP

```
Class names in UpperCamelCase
Functions in lowerCamelCase
Variables in lowerCamelCase

In databases, lower_snake_case (usually singular names)
```

**BillingController**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Leads;
use DB;

class BillingController extends Controller
{
    public $lead;
    public function __construct(Leads $lead) {
        $this->Date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $this->date = date("Y-m-d");
        $this->lead = $lead;
    }

    public function getInfo($user) {
        //Since this is an Eloquent model, you can fetch by id using Find or even FindOrFail
        $getUserInfo = $this->lead->find($user);
        if(empty($getUserInfo)) {
            return false;
        ) 
        else {
            //I assume this is an attribute and not eager loading, otherwise you need to load the relationship
            //with either with() function or load('relationship')
            return $getUserInfo->userInfo;
            //This will the attribute as a string.
            //If you plan on retrieving the object as an array,
            return $getUserInfo->toArray();
            //If you plan on receiving in any other format on the other side, you just change the return value.
        }
    }
}
```

**Leads Model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingTrait;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class Leads extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
     //protected $connection = 'mysql'; Why do you need this? unless you got different tables, theres no need, it uses what's in the env file
     protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
     protected $table = 'tableName_name';
     public $timestamps = false;
     protected $guarded = [];
}


?>
```

Comment: `protected $connection = 'mysql';` is used because i'm using multiple connection. Thanks it worked, but why i was getting as mentioned above when i `print_r($getUserInfo)`

Comment: `Echo will print anything you give him in a form of string. If it's an object, will print obj as a string` It's not true you can't echo an array or an object will give you array to string conversion error and same for object. I f you want to display an array or an object you can `print_r($array), print_r($Object)`.